# LimitEvent in full calendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I want to show single event on my calendar at time.i am using full calendar plug-in and view more plug-in.i called the event limitEvent(1).But it doesn't showing event if my event is long.For example my event is from Friday to next week Thursday.event is showing on Friday ,Saturday,Sunday. Event is not visible from Monday to Thursday.i am using view more button.But if I use limitEvent(2) it is showing proper format with 2 events+ view more button.Please help me on this I am using 1.5 full calendar plug-in

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the event limit.

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
       header: {
         right: 'prev,next',
         left: 'title'         
       },
       eventLimit: 2,// limit 2 row entry only 
    });
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation, please?

Comment: It's good practice on Stack Overflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work. For more information read [How To Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).